# Can not start Spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-shell

Hello I've unzip and exported spark path. Whne I lunch it I got this error.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/spark/spark24/bin
```

$ spark-shell

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/find_spark_home.py", line 74, in <module>
    print(_find_spark_home())
  File "/usr/local/bin/find_spark_home.py", line 56, in _find_spark_home
    module_home = os.path.dirname(find_spec("pyspark").origin)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'
/usr/local/bin/spark-shell: line 57: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

What's my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you set SPARK_HOME?

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark/spark24
```

Comment: Yes yes, I solve it. There old version files in /usr/local/bin/. I’ve deleted all these files and it works. Thanks